# Codeigniter and Session Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, windows-server-2012

Having an issue with some CI code here:

```
if((!empty($this->comm->GetSessionVar('TCSrch_ID')) || !empty($this->comm->GetSessionVar('TCSrch_Text')))){
    $tstxt = $this->comm->GetSessionVar('TCSrch_Text');
    $tsid = $this->comm->GetSessionVar('TCSrch_ID');
}


public function GetSessionVar($key){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('session');
    return (isset($_SESSION[$key])) ? $_SESSION[$key] : null;
}
```

Ubuntu Server has no issues with this, when it's uploaded to the production Win 2012 server, I am given the following error: `Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in DRIVE:\MY_PATH\application\models\tasks_m.php on line 19`

PHP version on Winbox is 5.3.1, on Ubuntu it's the latest  (5.5.x)

How can I fix this?

No, I cannot use CI's built-in session manager for this.

Comment: Are you using filesystem based sessions?

Comment: no.  CI sessions are uaing db.  PHP sessions use the default for IIS 8... which I think is cookies based

Comment: If you're not using CI's built in session manager, then where CI stores sessions isn't relevant. Are you moving your php.ini file up when you move your files? Just a thought.